# convert windows file name and path to unix conform names and vice versa in r

Tags: r, windows, unix

I am struggling with a solid way of converting windows file names/path into a unix format an vice versa.

My Problem, I have a tool in windows which produces a parameter file with a path to a file (sometimes multiple files) in windows format, for example `C:\Users\cf\Desktop\my.fasta;C:\Users\cf\Desktop\ecoli.fasta`. I normally split these strings by `;` to get a list of file names.

I develop my scripts on a unix system, so function like `basename` do not work with a path like this. Also the path will not be recognised as different folders. Furthermore, **the scripts I write should run on Windows and Unix systems**, so I need something which works on both machines.

Is there a way to handle file names in both OS types or maybe other functions I can use beside `str_split` and `gsub` and creating the path by hand?

Comment: Would love to get a comment for this vote down!

Comment: You can use `/`-separated paths in both windows and unix (like `C:/Users/cf/Desktop/my.fasta`). To sort out the first part of the path (which I guess will be different) you can use something like `ifelse(Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Windows", "C:/", "/")`.

Comment: @DGKarlsson So you would suggest to `gsub('\\\\', '/', file_names)` as a standard procedure? And Then some kind of replacement of `C:/Users` to `/mnt/windows_data`?

Comment: From your question it is not entirely clear what you want to do. If you only need your code to work for unix, you should probably change your tool to produce unix-style paths instead, but if you need it to work for both windows and unix you need to convert the paths in some way.

Comment: Not sure what the best solution is. The code should work on both OS. I expected some kind of splitting the strings uniquely and using `file.path` to create the path in a (hopefully) save way. But not sure how other people solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had this kind of problem in r, but I think that you can use the following function for splitting your ";"-separated list of paths and replace the windows-specific part of the path with the unix-specific part.

```
get.paths <- function(paths)
{
    file_names <- strsplit(paths, ";")[[1]]
    if (Sys.info()[["sysname"]] != "Windows")
    {
        file_names <- gsub('\\\\', '/', file_names)
        file_names <- gsub('C:/Users/', '/mnt/windows_data/', file_names)
    }
    file_names
}
```

This will return a vector with paths suitable for the system that you are running. Example (on unix):

```
paths <- "C:\\Users\\cf\\Desktop\\my.fasta;C:\\Users\\cf\\Desktop\\ecoli.fasta"
get.paths(paths)
 [1] "/mnt/windows_data/cf/Desktop/my.fasta"    "/mnt/windows_data/cf/Desktop/ecoli.fasta"
```

(and windows):

```
paths <- "C:\\Users\\cf\\Desktop\\my.fasta;C:\\Users\\cf\\Desktop\\ecoli.fasta"
get.paths(paths)
 [1] "C:\\Users\\cf\\Desktop\\my.fasta"    "C:\\Users\\cf\\Desktop\\ecoli.fasta"
```

Hope this is what you need.